# How to secure API keys and make dotEnv work for a very small Front-end app?

Tags: javascript, api-key, dotenv

So currently I'm creating a very small weather app using the Open Weather Map API, and I'm planning to host the app on GitHub Pages, but there's a HUGE security issue, the API key is perfectly visible in the JS file

And my solution was obviously to use DotEnv (I used it a lot when coding on the Back-end of my projects with Node.js), which made the values of certain variables hidden from the public.

So I did a `npm i -g dotenv` on the directory where my project is stored in, but there was a problem

I'm trying to use DotEnv for a *Front-end* project (so I must use DotEnv as an ES6+ module and not a CommonJS module)

Here's what I put at the beginning of my script:

```js
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
```

And for some reason that I cannot explain, the console throws a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` at the `import * as dotenv from "dotenv";`

To speculate, it might have something to do with the file structure of my project (look at the image down below)

[image: mage of the structure of my directories of my project]

I've seen tutorials on how to set up DotEnv for ES6+ on YouTube for JavaScript, but it didn't work for me...

**Is DotEnv exclusively for Node.js?**

**Is there another npm package that can hide sensitive credentials from the public for a *Front-end* project?**

I'd be very grateful if anyone would help

Comment: `Is DotEnv exclusively for Node.js?` yes

Comment: `Is there another npm package that can hide sensitive credentials from the public for a Front-end project?` no - you can't hide anything in the front end that the front end needs

Comment: You can't have anything in your client-side code or markup that's private from the client. It's **client-side**. If it needs to be secret, you can't give it to the client. More in the answers to the questions in [this search](/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=%5bjs%5d%20secret%20client%20side).

Comment: the way I would do it is to use your own server to proxy the request, adding the API key

Comment: have a handshake protocol, so your frontend contacts the back end for authorisation, the back end then passes an authorisation token to the frontend, if you lock that token to a single IP then even if the authtoken is captured or stolen it wont work on another ip address, you would need someway of authorising the frontend (username password, etc). but these would only need to be passed once to obtain the authtoken

Comment: if its just human readability you are worried about you can encrypt the key and store the encrypted string in the code, but if you want your code to operate you would need to include alll details for how to decrypt it in the code as well so while it would make it harder to find the key it wouldn't prevent someone determined to get it

Comment: @MikeT -`if you lock that token to a single IP` - I don't think open weather map have that option

Comment: @MikeT - though, I may have misunderstood what you're suggesting :D

Comment: its isn't an answer to your specific question is a comment on the generalities of how to secure a frontend, as stated before its impossible to truly secure a frontend so your frontend should request data from the back end which then uses its api key to contact open weather thus keeping the api key from every being seen by the frontend

Answer (score 2):

For a front-end application anything in the code will always be visible in some form to anyone who has access to the site. It is impossible to hide these values.

Dotenv is a package that can be used to help avoid keeping sensitive variables out of source control but will not help once the application is live as a website unfortunately.